# How to downgrade from version from Oreo to Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, migration, version

**My application need to run on on Android 6.0 it's actually in Version 8 I change the config in my gradle properties**

Also can't change my compile version it doesn't work ...

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.axem.rfid"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 29
    versionName "1.0.1"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

But my application still not work on the  device and I get no error I think maybe my activity may be a problem

```
   @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun doAfterPermission() {
    initAxemRoot()
    when (FileUtils.readConfigFile().parseRes) {
        FileUtils.CONFIG_FILE_EXIST_MALFORMED -> Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            getString(R.string.config_file_malformed),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        FileUtils.CONFIG_FILE_NOT_FOUND -> Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            getString(R.string.config_file_not_found),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }
    splashViewModel.checkLicence(Build.getSerial(), this)
}
```

So if you could help it would be really appreciated thanks !!

Comment: "not work" means ?

Comment: when I launch it on my device I get "Your App has Stop Working" .

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem here my code (if it can help someone) :

```
 fun hasPermissions(context: Context, vararg permissions: String): Boolean = permissions.all {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        splashViewModel.checkLicence(Build.SERIAL, this)
    }
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```